# Is PERL a must on LFS?

Tags: linux, perl

I am building LFS, and I am wondering about building PERL. Call me narrow minded, but I really want to try going on a Linux system without PERL, and have everything implemented in Python. 
Since I don't understand if perl is a dependency to another package, I am asking here...
Trying to remove Perl from Debian causes a havoc ... so I am wondering if there is a future for a linux system without Perl...

thanks, 
Oz

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perl needed for the installation and test suites of several LFS packages. After install you can deinstall Perl.

Comment: Thanks, I guess reading a little bit more down the road I would have found it...

Answer (score 2):

I don't quite understand what the issue is, even the latest version of debian does not come with perl pre-installed, or at least in it's default configuration.

Perl isn't a requirement in any shape form or fashion for a normal installation and dependencies on it are based on the packages that you want to use. If it requires perl then you'll either have to modify the source to utilise python or something else, or install perl.

Comment: thanks for the answer Dan, I just wanted to hear another opinion. Perl is pretty popular and many packages like TEX and GNOME depended on it later. On my new system I don't want to have gnome, but I would need latex ... So we will see how things develop...

Comment: For a long time Solaris didn't come with Perl either. It was common for admins to add Perl first thing, though.

Comment: @Dan, I just came back to this issue, and I think you are wrong. Check this out http://forums.debian.net/viewtopic.php?f=17&t=45804 according to this Perl is part of the required packages of Debian.

Comment: @Dan, for what I see so far Autoconf depends on Perl...

Comment: @Dan, Kbd depends on Perl too.

Comment: @Oz123 Happy to be corrected! I recalled somewhere in the deep dark corners of my memory that I had to install perl to get RT running on Debian 6.0 but I may have been mistaken or it may require something more than perl-base